# mbed HTTPText - no default constructor exists

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mbed

I'm using the mbed LPC1768, although the problem isn't really to do with the hardware. I am trying to use the standard example below to test out a HTTP client on the LPC1768. I have changed nothing at all in the example (I've seen it online but originally found in "Fast and Effective Embedded Systems Design" book).

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "EthernetNetIf.h"
#include "HTTPClient.h"

EthernetNetIf eth(
    IpAddr(192,168,0,101),
    IpAddr(255,255,255,0),
    IpAddr(192,168,0,1),
    IpAddr(192,168,0,1)
);

HTTPClient http;
HTTPText txt;

Serial pc (USBTX, USBRX);

int main() {
    pc.printf("\r\nSetting up network connection...\n\r");
    eth.setup();
    pc.printf("\n\nSetup OK. Querying data...\r\n");

    // attempt to access file 'mbedclienttest.txt' through the Internet...
    HTTPResult r=http.get("http://www/embeddedacademic.com/mbed/mbedcllienttest.txt", &txt);
    pc.printf("Result: \n\r\"%s\"\n\r", txt.gets());
}
```

It all seems pretty straight-forward, however I am consistently getting these errors:

```
Error: No default constructor exists for class "HTTPText" in "main.cpp", Line: 13, Col: 11
Error: Class "HTTPText" has no member "gets" in "main.cpp", Line: 24, Col: 46
```

I don't know why. I mean, I understand the errors, but the constructor exists in HTTPText and there is a gets method in the HTTPText file, too, so I really don't understand why I'm having a problem here. The HTTPText.cpp/.h files are in the `data` directory in `HTTPClient`. I think the second problem may well go if I know what is the cause of the first one.

In the coding window when it tells you where the functions are it is pointing to the right place, so I don't think it is a case of there being two different classes or something.

Noone else seems to have had this problem, so I'm assuming that this is most likely due to something I have/haven't done. Maybe it is due to the way the mbed developer environment handles things. I'm relatively new to the system so am still figuring it out.

As an extra note, if for some amazing reason it makes a difference, I had to include in the program folder the libraries EthernetInterface and mbed-rtos as one of the other libraries seemed to require a particular version of TCPSocketConnection and some of the lwip stuff.

Have I done something silly? This seems to work for other people with no questions asked in online examples. Any help appreciated.

Comment: That is no C. If it is C++, please add the tag yourself. C and C++ are **different** languages.

Comment: Apologies, I meant to write C++, cheers for the notice.

Comment: It looks like the error messages do not match the source code. If the line containing `txt.gets()` is line 25, then `HTTPText txt;` is line 14, not 21.

Comment: Corrected the error messages! I had copied them from when I had moved around `HTTPText txt;` and forgot to change them back.